# Raphael.js - Using fill attribute for a circle, makes the element in the circle disappear. How to avoid that?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Please see the code below. I am trying to draw a circle around a path (an icon made by Raphael.js founder, Dimitry) and then fill the circle with a color. This, however, paints on the top of the path. If I could first draw the  filled circle and then draw the path, this would be solved. But I need to reference the path because I need to find its center, in order to draw the circle. Can anyone please suggest how to do this? My code is below.

Thanks.

```
<script>
    var myVar = {
            s: 1,                           
            pw: 850,
            ph: 450
        }                   
</script>

<script>
    var paper = new Raphael('figSellerBuyer', myVar.pw * myVar.s, myVar.ph * myVar.s);

    var market = paper.path(paths.marketBoundary);
    market.attr({fill: "rgb(75,245,75)", stroke: "None"});


    var humanIcon = paper.path("M21.021,16.349c-0.611-1.104-1.359-1.998-2.109-2.623c-0.875,0.641-1.941,1.031-3.103,1.031c-1.164,0-2.231-0.391-3.105-1.031c-0.75,0.625-1.498,1.519-2.111,2.623c-1.422,2.563-1.578,5.192-0.35,5.874c0.55,0.307,1.127,0.078,1.723-0.496c-0.105,0.582-0.166,1.213-0.166,1.873c0,2.932,1.139,5.307,2.543,5.307c0.846,0,1.265-0.865,1.466-2.189c0.201,1.324,0.62,2.189,1.463,2.189c1.406,0,2.545-2.375,2.545-5.307c0-0.66-0.061-1.291-0.168-1.873c0.598,0.574,1.174,0.803,1.725,0.496C22.602,21.541,22.443,18.912,21.021,16.349zM15.808,13.757c2.362,0,4.278-1.916,4.278-4.279s-1.916-4.279-4.278-4.279c-2.363,0-4.28,1.916-4.28,4.279S13.445,13.757,15.808,13.757z")

    humanIcon.attr({fill: "rgb(75,75,75)"}).scale(2.5,2.5);
    humanIcon.translate(40,40);

    var bbox = humanIcon.getBBox();

    var xcenter = Math.round(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0);
    var ycenter = Math.round(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0);

    var circle = paper.circle(xcenter, ycenter, 40);
    circle.attr({fill:"white"});



</script>
```

Comment: Why not to just repaint the path on top of the circle once you've figured out its center? Probably not optimal but ought to do the trick.

Comment: Probably that would work. Should have thought of that. But I found a better solution; I have included it below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a lot of search on Google, I found the answer here on Stackoverflow. At the time, I did not save the link to the answer and I don't remember it. If anyone does find it, please edit this answer and post it. However, I did record the solution and here it is:

One can use the `insertBefore()` and `insertAfter()` functions in Raphael. In the example code given in the question, one can do this by changing the last line to:

```
circle.attr({fill:"white"}).insertBefore(humanIcon);
```

Thanks to those who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order in which the two are drawn. That or look over the Raphael docs to see if there is a "Z-index" attribute that can be used to permanently modify the position of the path on the stack of render-able layers.

Edit: I didn't read your explanation well enough. If you could declare your object without drawing it perhaps you could grab the BBox, and then draw it later.

Edit, Edit: SVG has a "defs" tag to create objects without drawing them, so it stands to reason that Raphael can handle it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Raphael's [Element.toBack()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.toBack) and Element.toFront().

In your case, it sounds like you want to draw the path, then draw the circle, then call  either `circle.toBack()` or `path.toFront()`.